# Proving that something is a submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

How can one prove that a connected set $S$ of a smooth manifold $M$ is a submanifold if there is a smooth map $f \colon M \to S$, such that $f_{|S}=id_S$. Shouldn't there be already a smooth structure on $S$ if you claim that $f$ is a smooth map, or they consider it as a smooth map $f \colon M \to M$? And why connectedness of $S$ is important? I don't have an idea to start with.

Comment: The map f is a map $M\to M$, so it makes perfect sense to say that it is smooth, even if $S$ were not a submanifold.

Comment: @Mariano Yes, but then in the setting of the problem, they should say that $f \colon M \to M$ is a smooth, shouldn't they!? Anyway, do you have any hints for me?

Comment: More properly, to say that $f:M\to S$ is smooth is to say that $f$ is a smooth function from $M$ to itself such that the range of $f$ is a subset of $S$.

Comment: As for why we need connectedness, I can give you an example. Consider $M$ to be the plane with $x$-axis removed (i.e. the manifold $\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2:y\not=0\}$), $S$ to be the union of the one-point set $\{(0,1)\}$ and the line $\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2:y=-1\}$, $f$ defined by sending all points of upper-half plane to the point $(0,1)$, and sending all points of lower-half plane to $\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2:y=-1\}$ by orthogonal projection. The set $S$ does not have a fixed dimension ($0$ at the point, $1$ at the line), and so it is not a submanifold...

Comment: ...You will use connectedness to prove $S$ has the same dimension at all points of $S$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realize hot to do it, with the help of comments, of course.Since $f \circ f=f$ on $S$, we have that $T_xf \circ T_xf=T_xf$ which means $im T_xf=ker(Id-T_xf)$. From Rank-nullity theorem and fact that rank cannot locally fall, we conclude that the rank of $f$ is locally constant, but since $S$ is connected, it is actually constant on $S$. Having constant rank is an open condition (as it can be easily deduced), so there is a neighborhood of $S$ on which $f$ has constant rank, and now by Constant rank theorem, S is a submanifold.